# how can injection dynamic html element to page with next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

how can dynamic injection html element to page with next.js? that these elements Unknown type like(input, checkbox, img,...). this element specified with api that return json type like this:

```
[{
   "id":"rooms",
   "title":"Rooms",
   "order":1,
   "type":"string",
   "widget":"select",
   "data":[{
            "Id":18,
            "ParentId":null,
            "Title":"One",
            "Level":null,
            "Childrens":[]
           },
            {"Id":19,
            "ParentId":null,
            "Title":"Two",
            "Level":null,
            "Childrens":[]
           },
            {"Id":20,
            "ParentId":null,
            "Title":"Three",
            "Level":null,
            "Childrens":[]
           }]
},
{
   "id":"exchange",
   "title":"Exchange",
   "order":0,
   "type":"boolean",
   "widget":"checkbox",
   "data":[]
}]
```

my try is:

```js
Index.getInitialProps = async function({req, query}) {

    const res= await fetch('url api')
    var elements= await res.json() 

    var test = () => (
        <div>
            {...... convert json to html elements.......}
        </div>
    )

    return {
        test
    }
})
```

```js
function Index(props) {
   return(
      <a>
        {props.test}
      </a>
   )
}
```

result is null, mean nothing for presentation.

the question is, Do I do the right thing? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What happens is that during the transfer of props from server to client in `getInitialprops`, JSON is serialized and so functions are not really serialized. See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3536

Your best bet is to convert the test data into a string of HTML data and inject it using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. An example will be:

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const text = '<div class="homepsage">This is the homepage data</div>';
        return { text };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="text-container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.text }} />
                <h1>Hello world</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The catch with this is that the string you return must be a valid HTML (not JSX). So notice I used `class` instead of `className`

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: thanks It was very useful.    But, Is this a usual injection method?

Comment: I won't say it is the go-to standard. There really isn't a goto standard. You could also return the json data and parse that into real JSX if you want