# how injection function with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

These codes work correctly, but I want to add onClick event to that (thank to @cr05s19xx in [how can injection dynamic html element to page with next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387778/how-can-injection-dynamic-html-element-to-page-with-next-js))

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const text = '<div class="homepsage">This is the homepage data</div>';
        return { text };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="text-container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.text }} />
                <h1>Hello world</div>
            </div>
        );
```

change to:

```
function func1(me) {
    console.log(me.options[me.selectedIndex].value);
}
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        var text = '<select onchange="func1(this)" >';
             text += '<option value="1"> text1 </option>';
             text += '<option value="2"> text2 </option>'
          </select>
        return { text };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="text-container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.text }} />
                <h1>Hello world</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

but output is this in browser:

```
             ReferenceError: func1 is not defined [Learn More]
```

make me happy with your help, please :)

Comment: You can't. Don't do this. Eval is evil.

Comment: What is better ???

Comment: You didn't provide all necessary details that are necessary to give a good answer in your previous question, so it was suggested that you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML, while in fact you can't . You have XY problem and need to do this without dangerouslySetInnerHTML but in a React way. If `select` needs a listener (`func1` is another needless abstraction because `select` has no such attribute), this needs to be done in a way it's usually done in React with `on*` prop. Consider reasking your previous question with all relevant details included.

Comment: oh sorry. Apparently, my question was wrong. edit      ...func1="func...      change to ===> ...onchange="func1...

Comment: You need to create these elements on the fly like `let Tag = 'select'; <Tag onChange={func1}/>` instead of treating them as HTML string with dangerouslySetInnerHTML.